# How to join tables by noting match and mismatch

Tags: sql

I have 2 input sql tables as shown below

table A

```
  Col1 Col2
  X     Y     
  R     S     
  Z     W
```

table B

```
   Col1 Col2
   X     Y     
   Z     W 
   A     Z
```

How can i join two tables by adding one more column as 0 or 1 in table A.

Expected Final Table would be.

```
  Col1 Col2      Code 
  X      Y          1
  R      S          1
  Z      W          0
```

I need to select all records from table 1 and need to add one more column for presence of col1 values in table 2 as 1 or 0. How can I implement this in sql?

Comment: What happens to row `A Z`?

Comment: It is left outer join.

Comment: Show the code for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` with a `CASE` expression to generate the `Code` column:

```
select a.fname, 
  a.lname, 
  case 
    when b.fname is null
         and b.lname is null
    then 0
    else 1 end Code
from a
left join b
  on a.fname = b.fname
  and a.lname = b.lname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/523ae/2)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with an `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    t1.fname,
    t1.lname,
    CASE WHEN t2.fname IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as code
FROM
    t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
    ON t1.fname = t2.fname
        AND t1.lname = t2.lname
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE` with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT fname, 
       lname, 
       Code = CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                            FROM   dbo.B 
                            WHERE  b.fname = a.fname) THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
              END 
FROM   dbo.A
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/523ae/4/0)

However, your desired result seems to be incorrect(X+Z are in Table B not X+R)

```
FNAME   LNAME   CODE
X         Y      1
R         S      0
Z         W      1
```